# Audio not working in ffmpeg video conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I am adding extra blank 1hour to my existing video using bellow command

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i universal.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=black:s=1280x720:r=24:d=5400" -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map [v] -c:v libx264 output.mp4  2>&1');
```

But out.mp4 is produced without any audio.Some one please guide me.

Comment: I removed the ffmpeg-php from your question. The ffmpeg-php tag is for questions about the php-extension, not for calling ffmpeg with exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether `ffmpeg` automatically copies audio stream if you don't specify otherwise. Try adding:

```
-acodec copy
```

This copies the audio stream if present. You can use `ffprobe` to see what streams and what codecs are used in both input and output files so check that they really contain audio streams.